# Output of ipython shell much slower than python shell

Tags: python, font-lock, ipython, comint

Even turning off `font-lock-mode` and set `(setq python-shell-font-lock-enable nil)`, the output of an ipython shell

`(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython")`

seems **much** slow than the python shell

`(setq python-shell-interpreter "python")`.

A test snippet would be

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=8, threshold=10000, linewidth=120)
np.random.randn(99, 99)
```

My emacs version is `GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1504.76) of 2017-01-14` and ipython version is `5.1.0`.

Is it possible to speed up the output of ipython shell ? Any help will be appreciated.